# I want to sort the string values of Object's Key in a given order. What would be the most optimized way?

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I want to sort "ONAIR", "READY", "CLOSING", "CLOSED" order in JavaScript.
Is it possible string value of Object's key in map or sort of JavaScript?

as is :

```
const list = [
{status: 'READY'},
{status: 'CLOSED'},
{status: 'ONAIR'},
{status: 'CLOSING'},
];
```

to be:

```
const list = [
{status: 'ONAIR'},
{status: 'READY'},
{status: 'CLOSING'},
{status: 'CLOSED'},
];
```

Comment: Is `[{...}, ...].sort((p, n) => p.status > n.status)` what you need?

Comment: No, as mentioned above I wanted a method of sorting unordered string values in an arbitrary order.. 'ONAIR' -> 'READY' -> 'CLOSING' -> 'CLOSED'.

Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean correctly.
Try this:

```js
const sortSequencely = ["ONAIR", "READY", "CLOSING", "CLOSED"];
const list = [
    {status: 'READY'},
    {status: 'CLOSED'},
    {status: 'ONAIR'},
    {status: 'CLOSING'},
];
console.log('Original list', list);
const listSorted = list.sort((a,b) => {
    const indexA = sortSequencely.findIndex(x=>x === a.status);
    const indexB = sortSequencely.findIndex(x=>x === b.status);
    return indexA - indexB;
})
console.log('Sorted list', listSorted)
```

Comment: your answers to my questions were good ideas. Thanks to you, I learned more about sort.

Comment: Try to use @Nick solution. It's a better way :). You are welcome

Comment: yeah I choose Nick's way in my project. but I thank to you, too.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is with a dictionary which specifies the order you desire; then you can sort based on looking up the `status` values in that dictionary:

```js
const list = [
  {status: 'READY'},
  {status: 'CLOSED'},
  {status: 'ONAIR'},
  {status: 'CLOSING'},
];

const order = { 'ONAIR' : 0, 'READY' : 1, 'CLOSING' : 2, 'CLOSED' : 3 }

list.sort((a, b) => order[a.status] - order[b.status]);

console.log(list)
```

Comment: I got a good idea from your answer.
Actually, I was in difficult situation because there was no comparative number value I can sort specific strings in object order. really helpful thanks

Comment: @jungjuyoung no worries - I'm glad this was helpful